# How to debug input method editor DLL in VS2011 on Windows 8?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, windows-8

I'm trying to debug an input method editor (IME) application. In order to run this sampleIme application DLL file generated, I must move the generated DLL file to windows\system32 directory and Register the generated dll file, Ime add in to the language bar.

How to debug input method editor DLL in VS2011 Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible, but a reasonably good workaround is to add code to your Visual Studio project to write variable values to a text file at points and times of interest.